# Elasticsearch scripting – Access per-field score

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, elasticsearch-painless

When scripting in Elasticsearch, the global score of a document can be accessed with `_score`.

However, in my case, I would need to **access the individual scores** with which **each field** contributes to the global score. E.g., by doing something like `_score["fieldName"]` (I know this is not possible, since `_score` is a double).

Is there any possible way this can be achieved?

Comment: I believe this is not possible, at least in the research I have done. The way to get the score of the field would be through the explain API but I think that doesn't suit you.
Out of curiosity, why do you need the field score?

Comment: @rabbitbr I see. Right, I don't think the explain API suits me, since what I need is search. My case is as follows: I have a text field with boost. However this field can be empty. For the docs where this happens, I would boost another field (via scripting).

Comment: Function score or script_score couldn't help? In both cases it is possible to know if the field has a value other than empty.

Comment: @rabbitbr that's a good hint :) However, if I'm not mistaken those queries let you decide how to score a field when that particular field is missing. My goal is slightly different: I need to score a field differently when *another* field is missing.